# How to display user_list in a indented line from the server in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a problem I have a site which displays users but it displays users not in a straight line but in an inverted pyramid. It could be because I am using django-filter app but it shouldnt create a problem as such. The profiles right at the end (especially in the mobile view) overlap and drag. It gets worse as profiles increase. Is it possible to align the profiles or user list in a straight line?

Please find below my code.

filters.py(for djang-filters app)

```
  import django_filters
  from userprofile.models import UserProfiles

class UserProfilesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
       model = UserProfiles
       fields = ['gender', 'age', 'Nationality','preference', 'Country', 
       'City']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profiles_list(request):
    filter = UserProfilesFilter(request.GET, queryset = 
    UserProfiles.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date'))
    return render(request,"userprofile/user_list.html", {'filter': filter})
```

user_list.html

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% block content %}
   {% load static %}
   {% load bootstrap %}




<div class="container">

<form class="form-horizontal col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4" action="" 
 method="get">
      {{ filter.form|bootstrap}} {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value='search'/>
   </form>

 {% for profile in filter.qs %}

 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


  <hr>

  <a href="{% url 'userprofile:profileview' profile.user %}"><h3>{{ 
  profile.user }}</h3></a>
  <br>
 <img src="{{ profile.image.url }}" class="rounded mx-auto d-block img- 
responsive float-left" style= "max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
 <br><br>
 <br><br> <br>
 <div class="font-weight-normal text-justify">
 Gender: {{ profile.gender }}
 <br>
 Country: {{ profile.Country }}
 <br>
 Description: {{ profile.summary }}
 <br>
 Preferences: {{ profile.preference }}
 <br><br>

  {% endfor %}
   </div>
   </div>
   <!--adnow ad-->
   <script type="text/javascript">
  (sc_adv_out = window.sc_adv_out || []).push({
    id : "575193",
   domain : "n.ads1-adnow.com"
   });
   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//st-n.ads1-adnow.com/js/a.js"> 
</script>
<div id="SC_TBlock_575193" class="SC_TBlock">loading...</div>
<!--adnow finishes-->





 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close your `div` tags in each `for` loop, since you start them within the loop.

Change:

```
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

to:

```
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) I am so dumb didnt realise this. Have a great day.